# scrollTo not scrolling the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure why this isn't working

html

```
    <a href="#" id="scrollTop" class="margin-top-40 btn btn-danger btn-lg top btn-not-100">Back to top</a>
```

jQuery

```
    $("#scrollTop").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(window).animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
    });
```

Even tried the following with still negative results

```
    $("#scrollTop").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("body, html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
    });
```

Css

```
    html, body {height:100%;}
```

Using jquery-1.10.2.js, consolle not giving any error

**UPDATE**
Comments below lead me to understand the issue is with using jQuery scrollTop and html, body set to overflow... Because of that [a new question has been created here on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124874/how-to-scrolltop-when-html-body-is-set-to-height-100).

Comment: Are you sure that the javascript is being loaded AFTER the html markup?

Comment: @dontvotemedown - it is valid (maybe not css).That should work. I use $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#elem').offset().top + 'px'}, 500); regularly

Comment: @FelipeMiosso yes, all other js is working fine

Comment: @jtheman nope, no difference at al

Comment: I put your code in jSfiddle, it works... http://jsfiddle.net/Asy9C/2/

Comment: Maybe you have `body { height: 100%; }` in your CSS

Comment: yes i do have body height: 100%

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in `$(function() { ... })`?

Comment: Try to replace `href="#"` with `href="javascript:;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the issue, thanks to comments I noticed I had `body: overflow-x:hidden` which means scrollTop isn't working when we are using overflow on body, html

Answer (score 1):

Well, your first *code* snippet won't work because `window` doesn't have a `scrollTop` *property* that `body` has *(that explains why your second code snippet it is supposed to  work fine - you can do `console.log($(window))` and check it's properties just to make sure)*.

However, you can do `$(window).animate(..)` and you won't see any *error* at *browser console*  because the *object* supports it. The problem is when trying to specify the `scrollTop` *argument* to the *animation* which is not supported by the affected *element* and it won't work as expected (*just comment the `e.preventDefault()` line from your second code snippet and see what happens - It is stopping script execution when testing and I really don't know why you are using that line)*.

By the way, I also don't know why you said that your second code snippet is not working *(maybe it depends on the browser you are using, at least it works using Chrome)*. So, as far as I remember, there were some problems when using just `body` or `html` *tag(s)* in the  *jQuery selector* for `scrollTop` but you can try this one `$('body,html,document')` for better *compatibility* and then *attach* the *animate function*. I'll recommend you to do some research about **how to scrollTop crossbrowser**.

Another recommendation *(if your second code snippet stills not working fine for you)* could be to check if your *DOM* was already loaded, maybe you can try using your code at *onDomReady* which means to put it inside `$(function(){ .. });` or  `$(document).ready(..)`.

**Live Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/n7Buw/2/

Comment: hang on, i have body height 100%, that's what causing it not to scroll!

Comment: If you test your first code snippet, you will see that the animation executes strange *(just comment `e.preventDefault()` line)*. I already tested this in another `jsfiddle` (which doesn't have *100%* `height`) and stills working strange. Take a look and test this http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/n7Buw/3/ *(that contains your first code snippet)* against this  http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/n7Buw/2/ *(that uses your second code snippet)* and see the difference.

Comment: however, we do have an issue with body 100% which completly makes the cose useless as it won't scroll at all regardless of the performance issues

Comment: the perfomance issue is what you said (which i haven't seen but that's not the issue for now), when you said is was "working strange". What's the point with what? The page uses 100% height for the sticky footer, but it has a scroll bar and i would like to scrollTop using jQuery

Comment: That's not *"performance"* it's *"behavior"* and I am not a `CSS` guru but if you are using `scrollTop: 0` then it is supposed to work. Also, your question just says that you were trying *"something"* and it is not working and my answer was to make you understand better about `javascript/jquery` code which gives you the right way to continue. If you want things done or still having problems make some research and don't forget to be more specific in your question and also include `CSS` tag.

Comment: i was clear enough with my question but thanks for you effort.

Comment: No worries but you said *"I am not sure why this isn't working"* and that's all. It is clear that you want someone to explain you what was happening and maybe *"solve"* something *(by your side)* but there are many situations in which other factors may cause other problems and *because of that* you must do some research and not just request things done. Following that line, your question just requests an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code worked for me on my site:

```
$("body, html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
```

So it must be the calling code. Perhaps you have duplicate id's. Type this in the console:

```
alert( $('*#scrollTop').size() );
```

Or you could use multiple selectors:

```
function myScrollTop( e )
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body, html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
}

// Map to future elements
$('body').on( 'click', '#scrollTop', myScrollTop );

// Get all elements with id if there are multiple
$('*#scrollTop').click( myScrollTop );
```

Comment: if i do alert( $('*#scrollTop').size() ) it gives me 0

Comment: Then your "Back to top" link must not be on the page? What about `alert( $('#scrollTop').size() )` (without the star)?

Comment: hang on, i have body height 100%, that's what causing it not to scroll!

Comment: Well, you also need to check the markup for your HTML. The event isn't even attaching to the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body {}

your_element {
  height: calc(100vh);
}
```

Comment: calc(100vh)? Calc isn't necessary here, just use height:100vh

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thanks for clarification. More detail, In my case: if html { height: 100%; } or html { height: 100vh; } than $(your_element).offset().top return 0. Thats why scrollTop not worked. My answer helped me.