# How to scrollTop when html, body is set to height: 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following won't work unless I remove `height: 100%` from body and html. However, i need that style as I am using it for other elements on the page.

**html**

```
<a href="#" id="scrollTop">Back to top</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#scrollTop").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(window).animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
});
```

Even tried the following with still negative results

```
$("#scrollTop").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("body, html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
});
```

**Css**

```
html, body {height:100%; min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Do they have overflows?

Comment: body and html? No, no overflow. Scrollbar is there

Comment: You need join on scroll event (jQuery) with scrollTop method (jQuery). In this way you know when user did scroll and with scrollTop you can set or get scroll values.

Comment: So overflow: scroll? Maybe post a fiddle - not entirely sure why your selector is body, html

Comment: overflow:scroll won't make any difference, actually it will create 2 scrollbars

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrollTo not scrolling the window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121948/scrollto-not-scrolling-the-window)

Comment: it's my own question with an UPDATE in it if you read

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got the issue, thanks to comments I noticed I had `body: overflow-x:hidden` which means scrollTop isn't working when we are using overflow on body, html

Comment: Solved my issue but why does setting overflow-x to hidden prevent scrollTop?

Comment: i don't know to be honest, hope someone will clear this in regards

Comment: note this happened to me with `overflow: auto` set, removing it did the trick. In case someone stumbles on this (like I did)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with `body { height: 100%; }` and `scrollTop(0)`.

Since I was not able to change html/css for different reasons,
workaround was to remove `height` before `scrollTop`, and then revert to initial state.

```
// Change height:100% into auto
$('body').css('height', 'auto');
// Successfully scroll back to top
$('body').scrollTop(0);
// Remove javascript added styles
$('body').css('height', '');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can just use min-height, it won't break the scroll functions. (tested in Chrome only)

```
body, html {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew Tibbetts: your question why does setting overflow: hidden prevent scrolltop.

As per my understanding, when we say overflow hidden, we are saying, we do not want to show the extra part, i.e please hide the extra part

So we do not want to scroll, that means scrolltop will always remain 0

since scrolltop, is how much we have scrolled upwards.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("#scrollTop").on("click",function(e){
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fvuy6/41/

Comment: mmm mine isn't, that should be it really

Comment: it's a plain copy of what i am doing with no luck

Comment: @rob.m Either it's the `e.preventDefault()` or there is another factor in your code/CSS that is causing the issue.

Comment: @rob.m Looks like you have it in an iframe of some sort, so you actually don't want to scroll `html,body` but that element. If you can't get it to work, you can always create another anchor and [scroll to its fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#scroll-to-fragid)

Comment: yea i can get to an anchor but that will jump and not have any animation

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.action', function() {
    $('html, body').css({height: 'auto'}).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#container").offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```